# WHERE clause ignoring rows in LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, where-clause, outer-join

I have three tables:

```
clinic = (id,name,short_name,region,country,continent,area) 
result_month =(id,year,result_quarter_id,month)
test_value_in_range_count =(clinic_id,result_month_id,patient_sub_set_id,test_value_range_id,number_of_values)
```

Sample data:

**clinic**

```
id      region      country     continent   area    
3299    Kazakhstan  Kazakhstan  Eurasia     Middle East/Asia
```

**result_month**

```
id      year    result_quarter_id   month   
200801  2008    2008Q1              1
```

**test_value_in_range_count**

no data for clinic id 3299 in **clinic** table. But the JOINS must return

I need to have all rows from **result_month** table with nulls from **test_value_in_range_count**. The problem is the `WHERE` clause. This stops from generating the rows because obviously data doesn't exist for certain rows from **result_month** into **test_value_range_id**.

**Expected Result**

```
clinic  region      country     continent   area                ym     vf
3299    Kazakhstan  Kazakhstan  Eurasia     Middle East/Asia    201511 null
```

I have tried lot of various queries by splitting them up but with no luck. Any help or direction would be really appreciated.

```
     SELECT
          apc.id AS clinic,
          apc.region,
          apc.country,
          apc.continent,
          apc.area,
          vrm.id AS ym,

        SUM(CASE test_value_range_id WHEN '1124_1' THEN number_of_values ELSE 0 END) AS avf

    FROM result_month vrm
        LEFT JOIN  test_value_in_range_count vt on  vrm.id = vt.result_month_id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN clinic apc on vt.clinic_id = apc.id

    WHERE (vt.test_value_range_id IN ('1124_1', '1124_2', '1124_3', '1124_4', '1124_5')) AND (vt.patient_sub_set_id = 'ALL')
    GROUP BY apc.id, 
        apc.region, 
        apc.country, 
        apc.continent,
        apc.area, 
        vrm.id   

        ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the condition from where clause and add it to the `join`:

```
SELECT
      apc.id AS clinic,
      apc.region,
      apc.country,
      apc.continent,
      apc.area,
      vrm.id AS ym,

    SUM(CASE test_value_range_id WHEN '1124_1' THEN number_of_values ELSE 0 END) AS avf

FROM result_month vrm
    LEFT JOIN  test_value_in_range_count vt on  vrm.id = vt.result_month_id and (vt.test_value_range_id IN ('1124_1', '1124_2', '1124_3', '1124_4', '1124_5')) AND (vt.patient_sub_set_id = 'ALL')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN clinic apc on vt.clinic_id = apc.id

GROUP BY apc.id, 
    apc.region, 
    apc.country, 
    apc.continent,
    apc.area, 
    vrm.id   

    ;
```

Else the where clause makes a `join` from your `left join`